# How to get the name of the current drive in Registry?

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-10, registry

I want to have an item in the context menu of a drive to run this command:

```
c:\windows\System32\manage-bde.exe X: -lock
```

I've added a key in this path in Registry:

> Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\runas\Command

The problem is that how can I replace `X:` in the above command with the drive that is right clicked on it? I tried `%1` but didn't work.

Comment: "%1" in this case is the drive root directory, e.g. "X:\", which isn't a valid parameter. You need an adapter that strips the trailing slash before running manage-bde.

Comment: @ErykSun Thanks. do you have any tips on how to do  that? I tried `%1:~0,2%` to take only 2 characters, still didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Use `REG_EXPAND_SZ` as the type for the `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\runas\Command` key and use `%~d0` to get the drive letter.

Comment: Thanks @BrechtSanders . apparently `%~d0` gives a value like D:\ but it needs to be without ending \ .. do you have any suggestions how to remove it? That's the same problem with %1

Comment: Sorry, I meant `%~d1` and you're right, that will have the trailing backslash.
For variables there is a replacement possibility, e.g. if you have variable `A` instead of `%A%` you can use `%A:\=%` to replace the backslash with an empty string, or `%A:~0,2%" to only use the first to characters.
But as `%1` doesn't have a trailing `%` that notation won't work. In a batch file you can use an intermediate variable (e.g. `SET A=%~d1`) to work around this.